# what could be a practical use for AIDL service

Tags: java, android

from what I understand, AIDL allows one app to call the service of another app... in order for AIDL communication to happen, you need to give your .aidl file to that other app so that it can call your service. Therefore both apps must share the same aidl file.

However I am not sure what practical use this could be. Can you englighten me how this could be helpful with a real life situtation ?

Comment: Almost all Android platform capabilities that are not basic unix-style features (sockets, files, etc) ultimately go through Binder IPC, with AIDL typically being what is used to give structured meaning to the data so interchanged.

Answer (score 0):

AIDL helps client and service to communicate with each other using interprocess communication (IPC).

One use I observed is IPackageStatsObserver.aidl from Package Manager. [AIDL](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/IPackageStatsObserver.aidl)

Helps to know about change in application size. Package Manager callback whenever size changes.

Comment: i need a little more detail, can you explain what you mean.. perhaps I am just a beginner with android

Comment: One process cannot access other process memory, they can communicate through IPC mechanisms. AIDL helps to define a contract or protocol they should follow. Like function definition, what data type etc.
 
Please read this doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html